# Laravel logout after form submit

Tags: php, laravel-4.2

I have a really strange problem. I have a form that has few images that are automatically there, they just change location. And that works normally. But when I try to upload image and submit form it logs me out. Here is the form:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="mainSlider" role="tabpanel">
                                        {{ Form::open( array('url' => URL::to('my-affiliate/save-main-slider'),  'id' => 'frmEditPageSettings', 'files' => true ) ) }}
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                                    <div class="push-right">
                                                        <button type="submit" style="visibility: hidden; margin-top: 0 !important" class="btn btn-primary btn-small"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-save"></i> SAVE SLIDER SETTINGS</button>
                                                        <select class="btn" style="float:right;width: 20%; padding: 5px;margin-top: 5px;" id="filterSlides">
                                                            <option value="3">Show All</option>
                                                            <option value="0">Show Active</option>
                                                            <option value="1">Show Inactive</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-body">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                            <!-- Tab panes -->
                                                            <div class="tab-content">
                                                                <div class="" id="mainSlider" aria-expanded="true">
                                                                    <div class="row">
                                                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                                            <br /><br />
                                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                                <div class="row">
                                                                                    <div class="col-lg-6 dropzone" id="dropzone">
                                                                                        <div class="fallback">
                                                                                            <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                                                        <ul class="images-path-container list-unstyled">
                                                                                            @if(count($mainslider) > 0)

                                                                                                <?php $i = 1; ?>
                                                                                                @foreach($mainslider as $image)
                                                                                                    <li>
                                                                                                        <div class="thumbnail" data-active="{{isset($image->show_image) ? $image->show_image : 1}}">

                                                                                                            <a class="remove-image btn btn-danger btn-xs" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa-fw fa fa-remove"></i></a>
                                                                                                            <img src="{{ URL::to($imagesUrl.$image->imagename) }}" /><br />
                                                                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="url[{{$i}}]" value="{{$image->url}}" placeholder="Slider URL" />                                                                                    @if($hasImages == true)
                                                                                                                <input type="hidden" name="image[{{$i}}]" value="{{$image->imagename}}"  />
                                                                                                                <input type="hidden" name="existing_image[{{$i}}]" value="1"  />
                                                                                                                <select style="margin-top:5px;" class="form-control" name="show_image[{{$i}}]">
                                                                                                                    <option value="1" {{ $image->show_image == 1 ? 'selected' : ''}}>Active</option>
                                                                                                                    <option value="0" {{ $image->show_image != 1 ? 'selected' : ''}}>Inactive</option>
                                                                                                                </select>
                                                                                                            @else
                                                                                                                <input type="hidden" name="image_to_copy[{{$i}}]" value="{{$imagesUrl.$image->imagename}}"/>
                                                                                                                <select style="margin-top:5px;" class="form-control" name="show_image[{{$i}}]">
                                                                                                                    <option value="1">Active</option>
                                                                                                                    <option value="0">Inactive</option>
                                                                                                                </select>
                                                                                                            @endif

                                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                                    </li>
                                                                                                    <?php $i++ ?>
                                                                                                @endforeach
                                                                                            @endif
                                                                                        </ul>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            {{ Form::submit('SAVE', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-small')) }}
                                        </div>
                                        {{ Form::close() }}
                                    </div>
```

and here is controller:

```
public function saveMainSlider(){
    AffiliateMainSlider::where('affiliate_id', Auth::user()->id)->delete();
    if(Input::has('image') || Input::has('image_to_copy')){
        if(Input::has('image')) {
            $images = Input::get('image');
            $show_image = Input::get('show_image');
            $existing_image = Input::get('existing_image');
            $urls = Input::get('url');
            $i = 1;
            AffiliateMainSlider::where('affiliate_id', Auth::user()->id)->delete();
            foreach($images as $k => $image) {

                $new_name = $image;

                if(isset($existing_image[$k]) && $existing_image[$k] == 0) {
                    $tmp = explode('.', $image);
                    $extension = end($tmp);
                    $path = "images/main_slider/".Auth::user()->id."/";
                    $unique_name = sha1(str_random(10));

                    $new_name = $unique_name . '.' . $extension;

                    if (!File::exists($path)) File::makeDirectory($path);

                    Image::make("tmp/{$image}")->resize(1920, null, true, true)->save($path . $new_name);
                }

                $mainslider = new AffiliateMainSlider();
                $mainslider->affiliate_id = Auth::user()->id;
                $mainslider->imagename = $new_name;
                $mainslider->url = $urls[$k];
                $mainslider->position = $i;
                $mainslider->show_image = isset($show_image[$k]) ? $show_image[$k] : 0;
                $mainslider->save();
                $i++;
            }


        }
        if(Input::has('image_to_copy')){
            $image_to_copy = Input::get('image_to_copy');
            $urls = Input::get('url');
            if(isset($image_to_copy) && count($image_to_copy) > 0){

                foreach($image_to_copy as $img_counter => $image){
                    $old_image = str_replace("images/main_slider/", "", $image);
                    $path = "images/main_slider/".Auth::user()->id."/";
                    if (!File::exists($path)) File::makeDirectory($path);
                    File::copy($image, $path.$old_image);
                    $mainslider = new AffiliateMainSlider();
                    $mainslider->affiliate_id = Auth::user()->id;
                    $mainslider->imagename = $old_image;
                    $mainslider->url = $urls[$img_counter];
                    $mainslider->position = $img_counter;
                    $mainslider->show_image = 1;
                    $mainslider->save();
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return Redirect::back()->with('success', 'Page settings saved successfully');
}
```

Here is route also, so you can see how I get to that method:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth|maintenance|force.ssl'), 
function()
{
    Route::post('/my-affiliate/save-main-slider', 'StoreController@saveMainSlider');
}
```

I use Laravel 4.2. Also for upload I use dropzone.js but it upload image to tmp folder properly so there's no problem with that. Does anyone know what could be the problem? This works normally in my local but not working on test or production server.
Tahnk you all in advance for your help

Comment: Does any code in your controller action execute, or does it take you immediately to the login page? What's the configuration for your test and production environments? Are they behind a load balancer? How are sessions configured on the servers?

Comment: It goes immediately to login page. There is no load balancer and session is stored in file.

Comment: Two more thoughts. Have you confirmed that a session cookie is actualy being returned by the server? Also you're using SSL. Are you using HTTPS only cookies? And if so, if the form being submitted to an unsecured URL and being redirected, hence losing the session cookie?

Comment: Session cookie is actually included in response and new session file is not created. Let me check your proposal for ssl

Comment: @fubar I tried with ssl bot still not working. Form is now being submitted to https and still same problem.

Comment: If the session file isn't created, have you checked your folder permissions? And have you checked your error log?

Comment: yes, permissions are ok, but still not working. There's nothing in log file